# "Given a condition, decide which execution should follow" with logic gates

Tags: logic-gates

[image]

For the system above I need to give 'SR' an input from *Hysteresis* or *Soft-Switching* blocks. Whether SR should read one or the other depends entirely on the condition ISB >= 0.5*REF. To visualize it better, imagine a simple ramp function:

[image]

Then, if ISB is lower than 50% of that ramp, 'SR' output should receive 
signals from *Hysteresis* block. On the other hand, if ISB is greater than 50% of ramp, *Soft-Switching* block should execute. In other words, it is like an if-conditional but in logic gates, if I'm not wrong.

If it helps, this is what is inside of [Hysteresis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQbuy.jpg) and [Soft-Switching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up6YK.jpg) blocks.

Comment: You are looking for a *multiplexer*.

Comment: Your verbal description doesn't make a whole lot of sense. The only time ISB > 0.5*ISB is false is when ISB is negative, so why not just compare ISB directly to zero? And what on Earth does *"give the instructions to SR"* mean?

Comment: And, you need a condition for ramp = 50%.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I corrected the "greater than" logic gate evaluation and "give the instructions to SR" text.

Comment: Hey, Zrakk, change your text too for completeness sake... Did you consider @DaveTweed comment yet?  I didn't do the math, personally, but I am lazy(-ish)... I was more about "oh look, multiplexer", but Photon beat me to it... Dave might have thought about it more :)